# metabase -How to create one query from several databases

Tags: datagrip, metabase

I created 3 queries from a different database.
which query has two fields: date and amount.
I want to compare between those 3 queries / creating delta on the amount.
how I can create it un metaBase or dataGrip?

Answer (score 0):

In DataGrip export each of the result into table. There is a button for export on the toolbar.

[image]

It can be any database of any vendor. And then work with these 3 tables.

By the way, in DataGrip any result can be compared with any result (but without migration): https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/executing.html#compare